# Performance benefit for storing platform invoke in delegate?

Tags: c#, interop

OpenTK does bindings to OpenGL by first defining a delegate with a matching signature to some target C function:

```
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
internal delegate void Uniform1f(Int32 location, Single v0);
internal static Uniform1f glUniform1f;
```

And then it assigns a value to `glUniform1f` that is returned from a platform specific OpenGL `GetProcAddress` function.

If I don't use OpenTK's approach, and instead just pinvoke the function using DllImport, will my code perform slower? (in otherwords, is there any performance benefit for using a delegate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if anything, there will be a performance *hit* (although incredibly insignificant in most cases) because you are using a delegate.

Remember, a delegate is a reference to a method.  Every time it's called, that reference has to be *derefrenced*.  Compare this to a method call that's compiled into your code; the runtime knows exactly where it has to go as the method reference is baked into the IL.

Note that delegate performance has improved *significantly* since .NET 3.0.  With the introduction of LINQ, delegates were going to be used extremely heavily, and with them being that ubiquitous, they *have* to be fast.

A possible reason you are seeing delegates being used is because the DLL that contains the unmanaged code needs to be determined at runtime (perhaps because of naming issues, processor-specific builds distributed together under different names, etc.).

In this case, an call is made to the unmanaged [`LoadLibrary` Windows API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), followed by a call to the unmanaged [`GetProcAddress` Windows API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Once the function poitner has been retreived, it is passed to the [`GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx) on the [`Marshal` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asx0thw2.aspx) in order to get the delegate.